# Materialize CSS dropdown inside ngFor Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, dropdown, materialize, angular-materialize

I'm trying to add a Materialize dropdown inside a table generate with *ngFor and the dropdown didn't show.
If I put the dropdown code outside the table it works.

```html
<p>Users enabled in this node: {{usersEnabled}}</p>
<p>Users in this node: {{users.length}}</p>
<table>
    <thead>

        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Enabled
        </th>
        <th>
            Actions
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>
                {{user.username}}
            </td>
            <td class="isLink cursorIcon" (click)="enableDisableUser(user.apiKey)">
                {{user.enabled}}
            </td>
            <td>

                <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
                <!-- <button class="btn" (click)="resetPassword(user)">Reset password</button> -->
                <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' data-target='dropdown{{user.apiKey}}'>Drop Me!</a>
                <ul id='dropdown{{user.apiKey}}' class='dropdown-content'>
                    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Typescript important methods

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  private getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsersByNodeApiKey(this.nodeKey).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.usersEnabled = res.filter((user: User) => user.enabled).length;
        this.users = res.sort((a, b) => a.enabled < b.enabled ? 1 : -1);
        M.AutoInit();
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {autoTrigger: true});
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

I'm using Angular 8 and Materialize CSS 1.0

Comment: try using ```data-activates = dropdown{{user.apikey}}``` in your anchor tag, instead of ```data-target```

Comment: With data-activates the console launch the following error: Can't bind to 'activates' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

Comment: See this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/materialize/materialize_dropdowns.htm

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add `[innerHTML]` which enables generated `html` inside your `table` like this

```
[innerHTML]="user.dropdown"
```

Where as `user.dropdown` may be an empty `string` defined in your `.ts` file or some value which you want to use in `drop-down`.

May be in your case `user.apiKey` can also be used.

Comment: I don't understand you. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the table / row in the view once users scope has it's data by add a

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users.length">
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
  .
  .
  .
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didnt worked for me. Also you only can add one template binding in the same element. Thanks you!

Comment: Surround the `<tr *ngFor="let user of users">` with `<ng-container></ng-container>` and add `*ngIf` to `<ng-container *ngIf="users.length"><ng-container>`

Comment: Update my answer, @MarcSerretiGarcia. Take a look.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. Take a look at the following link which I found in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8u0j59ay/11/. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that the problem is related with the ngFor and the dynamic data. The code outside the table works.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Marc Serret i Garcia... I have found a work around. Try if my provided solution works:-

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>
            {{user.username}}
        </td>
        <td class="isLink cursorIcon" (click)="enableDisableUser(user.apiKey)">
            {{user.enabled}}
        </td>
        <td>

            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <!-- <button class="btn" (click)="resetPassword(user)">Reset password</button> -->
            <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' [attr.data-target]='user.apiKey'>Drop Me!</a>
            <ul [id]='user.apiKey' class='dropdown-content'>
                <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
                <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Look for the changes that I have made - 
`<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' [attr.data-target]='user.apiKey'>Drop Me!</a>`

And the other for the id of dropdown - `<ul [id]='user.apiKey' class='dropdown-content'>`. It worked for me. Hope this helps.

Please look at my stackblitz:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/multipledropdown